# C small code won't work.

Tags: c, math

I was trying to make a small sqrtfunc to ease my homework today in math, but somehow it didn't work. Could you please help me? The program is just supposed to find the sqrt of a given number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sqrtfunc(double x);

int main(void)
{
    double y;
    scanf("%f", &y);
    printf("%f", sqrtfunc(y));

    return 0;
}

double sqrtfunc(double x) {
    double value;
    value = sqrt(x);
    return value;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What didn't work? is there an error message? Does it compile? Does it request a number?

Answer (score 5):

Use `%lf` conversion specification to read `double` with `scanf` and `%f` to print `double` with `printf`.

There is a false symmetry for floating point types with `printf` and `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now. Could you please explain, what's the difference between lf and f and why it must be used in this case .d ?
If i used f, the number the program outputed was very weird , something like 715648454 and a lot of zeros.
(btw this forum is amazing, omg, this is gonna help me alot on my quest to learn programming. i mean , i posted something, and a second later i got an answer. In some other forums i sometimes have to wait for hours, or even days :D .)

Comment: @geekkid `f` conversion specifier is used to read a `float` not a `double`. `double` are often 64-bit wide where `float` are often 32-bit: reading  with `f` will read only 32-bit of your `double` object. Technically the function call is undefined behavior as you pass a different type to the one that is expected for `f` specifier.

Comment: @geekkid: StackOverflow isn't a forum. It's a question-answer site. We don't usually have extended discussions or open-ended "topic"s here.